# Consuming SOAP web service in Xamarin Forms Portable Class Library (PCL)

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin, soap, xamarin.forms

I've made a web service in the ASMX format which I'm trying to consume in my Xamarin.Forms project. By default I cannot right-click "references" and click "Add Web Reference", it's just not there. However after I manually add System.Web.Services it appears. However when I try to add the web service I get an error "The method or operation is not implemented":

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Edit:
Profile in the project:
[image]

Comment: what PCL profile you are using? Can you add picture of your profile with checkboxes selected in it?

Comment: I edited the original post with the targets of the PCL project. Will that do or did you mean something else?

Comment: what VS you are using?

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2017 version 15.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Service Reference as shown in the picture. To get that option unload the PCL project, edit it. Find Profile259 and change it to Profile78

[image]

Comment: By default, right after creating the project I don't have that option. After adding a reference to System.Web.Services.dll the option appears, but trying to add the service reference after that results in the error from the original post (the method or operation is not implemented). I've tried multiple web services, so I don't think it's an issue in the web service.

Comment: You can go hard way https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

Comment: @Fayze Edited answer

Comment: BTW, remove your System.Web.Services.dll reference

Comment: Ahh, changing the profile allowed me to add a service reference. Thanks!